# How to include a bottom navigation view layout in an activity so that it appears below the listview items?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I have a Layout with a searchbar on the top, a listview and then a bottom navigation view. The problem is, the last item of the listview hides behind the bottom navigation view.

Here is the code of the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
       >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/snippet_searchbar" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </ListView>




        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"

     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For bottom navigation view:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/secondaryLightColor"
            >


        </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>



    </RelativeLayout>



</merge>
```

How can I resolve this issue so that the bottom navigation view appears below the listview and the last item of the listview with scrollbars appears above the bottom navigation even when scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: try to add some `android:paddingBottom="30dp"`

Comment: Instead `RelativeLayout` you can try `LinearLayout` and set orientation to vertical so it automatically arrange your views one below one.

Answer (score 0):

use height to define listView instead of using wrap_content or match_parent, in this way the bottom content and listView rows will not override each other

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the include layout and set the relative layout above the bottom navigation view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:id="@+id/rel1" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include layout="@layout/snippet_searchbar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </ListView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then start all over because this is the way to put a layout above another layout when you use Relative layout